# How to get three character string with extra zeros from interger using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get integer to `3` character string with extra zero's  like

`1 to "001"`

`23 to "023"`

`213 to "213"`

using `javascript` or `jquery`.

Comment: String.prototype.lPad = function (n,c) {var i; var a = this.split(''); for (i = 0; i < n - this.length; i++) {a.unshift (c)}; return a.join('')}
String.prototype.rPad = function (n,c) {var i; var a = this.split(''); for (i = 0; i < n - this.length; i++) {a.push (c)}; return a.join('')}
alert ('1'.lPad(3,'0'))
alert ('23'.lPad(3,'0'))
alert ('213'.lPad(3,'0'))

Comment: thanks for the answers  i just wanted to know is there any standard way of doing this  may be some method in jQuery so i can pass number of digit and number else functions we can always write.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
function left_padding_zeros(number, length) {
    var my_string = '' + number;
    while (my_string.length < length) {
        my_string = '0' + my_string;
    }
    return my_string;
}
```